# How to assign random colors to shapes in vb6 form

Tags: random, timer, vb6

I am developing a game using VB6.0, I want to generate randomly moving shapes (**circles, squares, rectangles, ovals, etc.**) with different colors in the background of form. I am using timers and shapes to achieve this.my contribution is furnished below.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    For i = 0 To 20
        s_left = Round(Rnd * 20050)
        s_top = Round(Rnd * 860)
        shape(i).Left = s_left
        shape(i).Top = s_top
        shape(i).Visible = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Now the problem is that, I can use only one shape and one color, is there any possibility to select a random color and shape within this Timer1_Timer()?

Comment: wait i have to check it out

Comment: reason for down vote? i got the correct answer for my question

Answer (score 1):

' the function that generate random colors

```
Public Function RandomRGBColor() As Long
    RandomRGBColor = RGB( _
        Int(Rnd() * 256), _
        Int(Rnd() * 256), _
        Int(Rnd() * 256))
End Function
```

your code should be changed as follows to get the requested result

```
dim shape_style as integer
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
For i = 0 To 20
shape_style= Round(Rnd * 5)
s_left = Round(Rnd * 20050)
s_top = Round(Rnd * 860)
shape(i).Left = s_left
shape(i).Top = s_top
shape(i).Visible = True
shape(i).fillcolor=RandomRGBColor()
shape(i).shape=shape_style
Next i
End Sub
```